# Using javascript media query to change the class of 2 divs

Tags: javascript, media

```
<script>
     $(window).resize(function(){
     console.log('resize called');
     var width = $(window).width();
     if(width >= 900){
         $('#lefty').removeClass('alpha');
         $('#righty').removeClass('omega');
     }
     else{
         $('#lefty').addClass('alpha');
         $('#righty').addClass('omega');
     }
   })
   .resize();
</script>
```

I'm trying to use this code to add/remove the alpha and omega classes to the two divs (lefty and righty).

After some firebug debugging this code never even gets executed and I'm not entirely sure why.

It may or may not be relevant, but the divs this code should be altering is in a php include like this:

```
<?php
  require ("include_nav.html");
?>
```

I don't know enough about javascript to know why this isn't working! Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in your code is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/ccjyD/

Reasons it might not be called:

- It is called before jQuery is loaded.
- There is some syntax error before `$(window).resize...` causing it not executing the event listener.
- Error in your PHP file.

---

### Update

Most of the time if an event listener only fires once, it is because of this:

```
$(window).resize(yourFunc());
function yourFunc(e){  //^------shouldn't have ()
    //blah
}
```

If you used an anonymous function instead of this, then there must be other problems in your code.

Comment: Ah ok I had jQuery being included directly after the function, rather than before!


However, after swapping them around my function does get called when you first load the page, but not again after that (nor does it work when the page is first called). Any ideas?